# Can anyone help in finding the errror in the following code of quicksort,its's showing Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, segmentation-fault, quicksort

#### CODE FOR QUICKSORT

I have used a partition function to get the pivot and after that which recursion solving the problem, but while compiling it is showing segmentation fault.

```
void swap(int* a,int* b)
{
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

int partition (int arr[],int start,int end)
{
    int piviot=arr[end-1];
    int pindex=start;
    for(int i=start;i<end-1;i++)
        if(arr[i]<=piviot) 
        swap(&arr[i],&arr[pindex++]);
    swap(&arr[end-1],&arr[pindex]);
    return pindex;
}

void quick_sort(int arr[],int start,int end)
{
    if(start<end)
    {
        int pindex=partition(arr,start,end);
        quick_sort(arr,start,pindex);
        quick_sort(arr,pindex,end);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to exclude the pivot from the subarrays when recursing, which will blow the stack. Make the second call `quick_sort(arr, pindex + 1, end)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
```

{ 
    if (low < high) 
    { 
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

```
    // Separately sort elements before 
    // partition and after partition 
    quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1); 
    quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code

```
void quick_sort(int arr[],int start,int end)
{
    if(start<end)
    {
        int pindex=partition(arr,start,end);
        quick_sort(arr,start,pindex);
        quick_sort(arr,pindex,end);
    }
}
```

If `pindex` equals `start` then `quick_sort(arr,pindex,end);` will call the quick sort function with the same parameters resuling in a stack overflow (ta da!!).

The point of quick sort is that the pivot element is in the correct position, so you recursively sort everything but the pivot element.

Something like

```
        int pindex = partition(arr, start, end);
        quick_sort(arr, start, pindex);
        quick_sort(arr, pindex + 1, end);
```

Untested.